# Split the results from urrlib

Tags: python

Need to import data from the ISS.
Use the code

```
r= urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.celestrak.com/NORAD/elements/stations.txt')
x=r.read(1000)
```

when I try to split the data with

```
x=x.split("\r\n")
```

I get the error

```
raceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
x=x.split("\r\n")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which version of Python? It looks like 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)?

```
import requests

response = requests.get("http://www.celestrak.com/NORAD/elements/stations.txt")
text = response.text.split("\r\n")

for t in text:
    print t
```